# Is it possible to programmatically supersede the native hyperlink-following behavior in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, hyperlink

Is it possible to supersede the built in way in which Excel follows hyperlinks once they are clicked?

Specifically, I have a .pdf document that contains hyperlinks, which I open in an Excel userform. When a user clicks any of the links in that document, I'd like to programmatically abort the usual behavior of attempting to open the target of that link in a new browser window.

Instead, I'd like to perform some text string manipulations on the URL target of each of those links, and use the result to drive some other VBA code.

---

For example, say the .pdf file has a hyperlink whose target is "http://www.website.com/1234".  When this link is clicked, I'd like the end result to be an Excel/VBA command of `msgbox "1234"` with no attempt made to actually open the URL in a browser.

---

Is such a thing possible in Excel?

If not, is it possible to do the same thing in Access?

Comment: Check out the [Follow Hyperlink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838843.aspx) worksheet event, that should be able to pre-empt the opening of the browser.  Do you know enough VBA to get going from there? If you try something and can't get it, please post the code and we can tweak/try to fix!

Comment: @BruceWayne Thank you yet again for your help here. I suppose that the available events in Excel are a little opaque to me. I have a little bit of experience working with Access, where all available events are always spelled out in the properties tab. Based on your answer, I am starting to see that it's worthwhile to explicitly research what events are available in various settings in Excel. Again, thank you!

Comment: (As a small bit of meta...I hope that this question is not too similar to the longer one I asked a few days ago that you also helped with! Although the more I think about, this probably is a duplicate, although I hope that this one is a better-formed and clearer question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Worksheet_FollowHyperlink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838843.aspx) event macro to override default hyperlink behavior..

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    MsgBox "1234"
End Sub
```

Alternately, for a workbook-wide approach, the [Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838573.aspx) is available.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    if Sh.Name = "Sheet1" Then _
        MsgBox "1234"
End Sub
```

Comment: (1 of 2) Thank you very much for this. I feel like this is definitely the right approach, but I'm having two issues getting all the way there. First of all, following your advice, I've placed the following code behind Sheet1: `Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
MsgBox Target.Address
End Sub`  The first thing I'm noticing is that it seems like this event will only fire if I enter a hyperlink within a regular cell on sheet1. Clicking a link within the .pdf/userform has no effect (it opens neither the msgbox nor the link/browser). **continued**

Comment: To confirm: This is s PDF opened by an embedded IE browser in a UserForm...? If it is, you may have to isolate either IE's messager queue or the window system message pump rather than an Excel event macro.

Comment: (2 of 2) I'm not sure that this has anything to do with the code itself, though. I get the same (non)-behavior in the userform if I comment all of that code out. It also doesnt seem to matter whether or not I add similar code behind the userform itself instead of the sheet. ---------------- The second thing I am noticing is that, even if I add and then click a link in a regular cell, the message box does display as expected, but the same link will then nonetheless open in a browser afterwards. I don't seem to be successfully avoiding the browser navigation. Adding an `End` statement is no help

Comment: I'm currently using the .pdf viewer control. Might I have better results with a browser control instead? (It sounds like the answer is yes) :)

Comment: I would have to set up a test environment to answer that definitively but you can control anything if you are capturing the right message queue and message type.

Comment: Switching the control type from .pdf viewer to WebBrowser does indeed make the embedded links clickable once again. But I'm not catching the FollowHyperlink event from that userform at the moment (clicking the link just opens the target in the userform webbrowser control, as normal). I'm trying to place similar code behind the userform and the webbrowser control at the moment to see if that gets it. I do just now notice your comment about the IE messenger queue/windows message system pump, which I will move onto next. :)

Comment: Interacting with the message queue via VBA seems to be an especially daunting task, from what I've been able to discover over the last few hours. I've activated MSMQ, but I'm feeling quite lost about how I ought to proceed from here. So far the only code examples I've found online pertain to VB6, and its not clear to me if/how they might work in VBA. With apologies for the *painfully vague* question....do you have any pointers that might help me get started? :)

Comment: I've been thinking about this off-and-on over the couple hours and capturing the hyperlink event in the Internet.Explorer object may be a better method. However, you have to remember that what you are trying to do is completely contradictory to **by-design** behavior and HTML/browsers are somewhat specifically designed to **NOT** let anything redirect a hyperlink 'click'. With that said, I'll keep thinking about it; are you in a specific hurry?

Comment: Another meta-type question, I'm afraid....it seems to me that perhaps the thing to do here would be to ask you to edit your answer to include an explicit reference to pursuing a message queue type solution for passing parameters between .pdf and excel in the way I am hoping to do. I should then accept that answer as the solution to my original question, and then pose a new question thread concerning the particulars of how to implement a message queue type of solution here. Would that be in keeping with the intended rules of the road here on SO?

Comment: Not in a major hurry, thank you. (Once again, I very much appreciate the thought and help!) And that is a good point about about attempting to co-opt the intended behavior of links; I am only trying to leverage links because I haven't had success finding any other structure or object that appears capable of passing the kind of information between .pdf and excel that I am hoping to facilitate. Perhaps hyperlinks are not the best object to accomplish this, but I haven't had any luck finding a workable alternative so far.

Comment: (1 of 2) This is a little off the wall, but maybe there's some hope here. At heart, what I'm trying to do is be able to pass information from each of many clickable objects in a .pdf file, and have some information associated with each of those clickable objects programmatically-available to a sub in Excel using VBA. I've been trying to accomplish this using modified hyperlinks, in part because I haven't been able to get JavaScript running in my .pdf file to work with any objects in Excel. **continued**

Comment: (2 of 2) Instead, Im pretty sure I could write *different* JS in .pdf that would, say, save a blank 1-page .pdf document to a particular subfolder, and *name* that dummy file the same text string that I had previously been hoping to pass via a modified hyperlink. As long as its possible for Excel/VBA to have access to an event that fires whenever a file is added to that folder, then I could grab the text string in Excel simply by referring to the name of the new dummy file. I'm not sure if **this** is possible either, though. A quick google search suggests "WMI events" might work.Not sure yet.

Comment: (1 of 2) Tentatively, this seems to work. It's not pretty, but it seems to work. And it turned out to be even simpler than using WMI events. Since I have complete control over the contents of the dummy folder and dummy files I'm setting up to handle this information transfer, I don't need to develop a robust method of testing whether or not there have been changes to the dummy folder--I can use very simple, everyday VBA code to test whether or not the folder is empty. That way, I set up an empty subfolder initially...my JS in the .pdf file will save a dummy doc into that folder **continued**

Comment: (2 of 2) into that folder whenever a link is clicked, and the name of that dummy file will be the text string that I need to pass to Excel. I have a simple sub in Excel that continually tests whether that folder is empty (by looping every X seconds to test whether the Dir() function for that subfolder & "*.*" is a ZLS). If that procedure ever finds a file in the designated subfolder, it captures the filename string,deletes the dummy file, and then executes the business end of my code. Again, kind of clumsy but it seems like this is going to work. I'm sure there are better ways of doing this.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, @jeeped and @brucewayne!